# WordPress Awesome Support plugin hook not triggered

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not that new with WordPress and PHP but I don't understand a function anymore. Which function? This here:

```
add_filter( 'wpas_ticket_status_updated', 'test' );
function test( $post_id, $status, $updated ) {
    error_log( 'updated' );
}
```

My plan is to log out a ticket when it's getting updated to export the log for testing purposes. So I've took a look into the developer documentation of Awesome Support and found the hook above:

https://developer.getawesomesupport.com/documentation/hooks-and-filters/wpas_ticket_status_updated/

So I've implemented it into my `function.php` (the normal way) and created a ticket. So the status needs to be created. After this I've changed the status of the ticket to in progress but I got nothing. Nothing about the creation and nothing about the status change.

What I'm doing wrong? I don't get it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of the plugin, you are mixing `filters` and `actions`. Based on your provided code you are trying to trigger your `test` function once the filter `wpas_ticket_status_updated` is called. However, this function is not a filter but an `action`, therefore your hook is never to be called.

You should therefore change your code to `add_action('wpas_ticket_status_updated', 'test')` or find a related filter to call your desired `test` function.